# Using cron to automate backing up server with rsync doesn't work

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, cron, rsync

I have a **linux server hosting Minecraft** that I can connect to using ssh, I should probably also
mention that I do have an ssh key with no passphrase.

I want to backup my Minecraft world every hour to my **local pc** in a backups/minecraft_backups folder

I have a bash script in **/etc/cron.hourly** that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -re ssh --delete root@<server-ip-address>:/root/minecraft/world/* ~/backups/minecraft_backups/$(date "+%B%d-%Y")
```

The script **works perfectly** if I run it on its own but, for some reason, the **cronjob doesn't work**(nothing happens).

Comment: Check the system logs.

Comment: Feb 11 15:17:01 johna CRON[117933]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly), this is the last log, when I scan through all of them I don't see anything relating to my command?